# hyperref: new bookmark, full-page floats

Tags: hyperref

The `hyperref` package automatically creates a list of "Acrobat bookmarks" – a table-of-contents tree that is not part of the printed document, but can be accessed in a PDF reader (typically it is displayed in a side panel next to the document).

All sections, subsections, etc. are automatically added to the list. However, I would like to add additional entries.

I have a somewhat tricky situation: At the very end of my document, I have `\clearpage`, which is followed by a number of full-page floating `figure` environments (and nothing else). I would like to have a bookmark that looks like `\subsection` and takes me to the first page with a full-page float (the page right after `\clearpage`).

How can I do that?

If I add something like `\phantomsection \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Figures} \null` between `\clearpage` and the first full-page float, I will have an additional empty page in my document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't figure out why it doesn't work to just do what you're doing, or why putting the `\addcontentsline` inside a `\AtNextShipout` doesn't work. That said, it seems to work if you put it in the figures.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\section{asdf}
asdf
\section{qwer}
\clearpage
\begin{figure}[p]
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Figures}
\noindent
\rule{4in}{6in}%
\caption{X}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[p]
\noindent
\rule{4in}{6in}%
\caption{Y}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[p]
\noindent
\rule{4in}{6in}%
\caption{Z}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
Actually, just after I posted this, I had a thought. The `\write` gets put on the main vertical list, but this is never shipped out. Yeah. Add a `\clearpage adsf` after the last figure with the `\phantom\addcontentsline...` before the figures and sure enough, the bookmark is to the text after the figures.

I'm still not sure why it doesn't work `\AtNextShipout`. I'd have to check the package again, but I'm pretty sure that does something like changing `\shipout` into `\afterassignment\shipouthook\setbox0=` and then the `\shipouthook` inserts the material into the box and uses `\aftergroup` to perform the real shipout once the `\vbox` in `\shipout\vbox{...}` from `\@outputpage` is closed.

Answer (score 3):

Use a bookmark which takes you to the target.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\section{foo}
bar
\newpage
\section{Another Section}
\clearpage
\begin{figure}
\hypertarget{figures}{}
\pdfbookmark[2]{Figures}{figures}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=0.8\textheight]{foobar}
\caption{my caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=0.8\textheight]{foobar}
\caption{my caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=0.8\textheight]{foobar}
\caption{my caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```